# Swift 4 JSONSerialization.jsonObject

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I am using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4. How can I check if the returned json data is null?
Now it gives me error `Type 'Any' has no subscript members` at line `if json[0]["data"]`

```
var json: NSMutableArray = []
var newsArray: NSMutableArray = []

let url = URLFactory()
var data = try! NSData(contentsOf: url.getURL()) as Data
do {
    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSMutableArray
    if json[0]["data"] {
        // data is not null
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // handle error
}
```

My JSON returns something like this:

```
{
   "data":
   [
      {
         "news_id":123,
         "title":"title",
         "news_date":"2017-02-08 21:46:06",
         "news_url":"url",
         "short_description":"description",
         "category_id":4,
         "category_name":"Health",
         "latlng":
         [
            {
               "lat":"43.003429",
               "lng":"-78.696335"
            }
         ]
      }
      { ....
}
```

Comment: Don't use `NS[Mutable]Array` or `NS[Mutable]Dictionary` in Swift. Use native collection types.

Comment: Please read the JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only two collection types: `{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array. The root object is clearly a dictionary (`[String:Any]`). And the *has no subscript members* error occurs because in Swift 3+ the compiler must know the static type of any subscripted collection type.

Comment: Don't use _any_ of the `NS` types you have here, including `NSData`, `NSError`, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using Swift 4, I might suggest `JSONDecoder`:

First, define the types to hold the parsed data:

```
struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let data: [NewsItem]
}

struct NewsItem: Codable {
    let newsId: Int
    let title: String
    let newsDate: Date
    let newsURL: URL
    let shortDescription: String
    let categoryID: Int
    let categoryName: String
    let coordinates: [Coordinate]

    // because your json keys don't follow normal Swift naming convention, use CodingKeys to map these property names to JSON keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newsId = "news_id"
        case title
        case newsDate = "news_date"
        case newsURL = "news_url"
        case shortDescription = "short_description"
        case categoryID = "category_id"
        case categoryName = "category_name"
        case coordinates = "latlng"
    }
}

struct Coordinate: Codable {
    let lat: String
    let lng: String
}
```

And then you can parse it:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
do {
    let responseObject = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(responseObject.data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Clearly, if your JSON is different, you might need to change your objects accordingly (e.g. it struck me odd that `latlng` was an array of coordinates). Also, you can define custom `init(from:)` methods if you want to convert some of these strings into numbers, but I'd rather fix the JSON, instead (why are `latlng` returning string values rather than numeric values).

For more information, see [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

---

As an aside, I'd advise against this pattern (note, this is your network request logic, but excised of `NSData`):

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url.getURL())
```

That will retrieve the data synchronously, which can be problematic because

- the app will be frozen while the data is being retrieved resulting in a poor UX;
- you risk having your app killed by the watchdog process which looks for frozen apps; and
- you don't have robust error handling and this will crash if the network request fails.

I'd suggest using `URLSession`:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url.getURL()) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    // now parse `data` like shown above

    // if you then need to update UI or model objects, dispatch that back
    // to the main queue:

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // use `responseObject.data` to update model objects and/or UI here
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: The latent values in the database are type decimal(10,6) I don't know if this is what's making it return as string! news_id is type integer in database and returned as integer.